# Does Realm support computed property in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to use a computed property in Realm and use it as primaryKey.

```
dynamic var eventPrimaryKey: String{
    get{
        return "\(ID)\(eventId)"
    }
}
```

but I receive this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Primary key property 'eventPrimaryKey' does not exist on object
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming `eventPrimaryKey` to something else?

Answer (score 6):

You can't use computed property as a primary key, primary key should be stored in database. See more info about primary keys in [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys).

Check out [Ignored Properties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#ignored-properties) also (note: read-only properties are automatically ignored).