# How do I force include computed property?

Tags: swift, realm

How do I tell realm that I want it to compute and store read-only property? Let's say I have following model:

```
class User: Object {
    @objc dynamic var fullName: String {
        return "\(name) \(surname)"
    }
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var surname = ""
}
```

I'd like to have formed full name on write action. Is it possible w/o using workaround with dummy setter?

Comment: I have no experience with Realm, but could this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718946/does-realm-support-computed-property-in-swift ?

Comment: @MartinR, I think it could be in some way. Maybe it worth to answer my question with workaround? I think it could help people.

Answer (score 1):

Read-only properties are automatically ignored because it makes absolutely no sense to store them in a database. If you really need to store it in a database, you can create an update function to your User class and use it for saving the entity to database.

Something like this:

```
class User: Object {
    @objc dynamic var fullName = ""
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var surname = ""

    static func create(name: String, surname: String, in realm: Realm) {
        let user = realm.create(User.self)
        user.name = name
        user.surname = surname
        user.fullName = "\(name) \(surname)"
}
```

Then you just create your entity like this:

```
...
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    User.create(name: name, surname: surname, in: realm)
}
```